# Repainting of JavaFX window

Tags: java, javafx, repaint

Is there any option to REPAINT opened window of javafx application? I need to repaint this window in loop (i=1000) and check time from start of repainting to end of repainting.

I do not know where and which method use.  Thanks a lot

```
public class JavaFxCombobox extends Application {

private static final int numberOFTestingLoops = 100;

private List<Long> resultOfAnalysisRepaint = new ArrayList<Long>();
private List<Double> resultOfAnalysisMemory = new ArrayList<Double>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    int counter = 0;

    List<ComboBox<String>> comboboxes = new ArrayList<ComboBox<String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {

            counter++;

            ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
            comboBox.getItems().addAll(Integer.toString(counter), "test1",
                    "test2");
            comboBox.setValue(Integer.toString(counter));

            comboboxes.add(comboBox);

            gridPane.add(comboboxes.get(counter - 1), j * 30, i * 35);
        }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(1550);
    primaryStage.setHeight(670);
    primaryStage.show();

}   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is probably the [Timeline Animation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm). It allows you to describe the state each frame and change frames with delay.

Comment: I do not know if this is that what I need. I have JavaFx app with e.q. 1000 buttons and I have to repaint all content of this window in loop (100x) and count how much microseconds it was for one loop.

Comment: Please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23059340/2381172. There is no way to repaint JavaFX components on demand. If you need to change their style sequentially then the animation could help.

Comment: I tried have a look on this link but I am not sure how to use it. Can you give me show what should I change (add to) in my code?