# Custom ListCell implements InvalidationListener, repaint components

Tags: javafx

I have a custom `ListCell` implemented that contains a `BorderPane` layout with some components.

The cell registers itself to the item. So when the duration of the item changes the `invalidated` method is called.

In this method I set the text of the duration label. My problem is now the method is called but the label is not repainted.

I think if setText is called the cell should repaint. It is possible to manually repaint the cell or the Label.?

```
public static class ListItemCell extends ListCell<MusicListItem> implements InvalidationListener{

    private AnchorPane listItem;
    private Label artist;
    private Label title;
    private Label duration;
    private BorderPane borderPane;
    private FlowPane flowPane;

    public ListItemCell() {
        initCellLayout();
    }

    public ListItemCell(final LogicInterfaceFX logic) {
        ...
    }

    public void initCellLayout() {
        try {
            this.listItem = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/de/roth/jsona/view/themes/" + Config.getInstance().THEME + "/" + "layout_list_item.fxml"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.borderPane = (BorderPane) listItem.getChildren().get(0);
        this.flowPane = (FlowPane) borderPane.getLeft();
        this.artist = (Label) flowPane.getChildren().get(0);
        this.artist.getStyleClass().add(defaultTextClass);
        this.title = (Label) flowPane.getChildren().get(1);
        this.title.getStyleClass().add(defaultTextClass);
        this.duration = (Label) borderPane.getRight();
        this.duration.getStyleClass().add(defaultTextClass);

        this.setGraphic(listItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(MusicListItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (!empty && item != null) {
            item.addListener(this);
            item.durationProperty().addListener(this);

            // Duration
            this.duration.setText(item.getDuration());

            // Artist / Title
            if (item.getArtist() != null) {
                this.artist.setText(item.getArtist());
                this.title.setText(" - " + item.getTitle());
            } else {
                this.artist.setText("");
                this.title.setText(item.getFile().getName());
            }
        } else {
            this.artist.setText("");
            this.title.setText("");
            this.duration.setText("");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        System.out.println("INVALIDATE!!!" + getItem().getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        this.duration.setText(getItem().getDuration());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work (though you have a memory leak). Is it passing the value you expect to the `setText(...)` method?

Comment: A memory leak in java? I tried so many things to bind the changed value, nothing really worked for me. I like JavaFX very much but custom listcells is really a pain in the a... ;) What could have caused the memory leak?

Comment: You caused the memory leak :). The updateItem(...) method is (potentially, at least) called arbitrarily many times during the lifespan of the cell (i.e. as long as the `ListView` is in scope). Each time, you add another copy of the listener to item.durationProperty(), but you never remove those listeners. If you scroll around a bunch, you should find your output getting more and more verbose.

Comment: Ah ok, you're right. But 20 or 100 or 1000 listener should be no problem to handle. The listCell does not repaint. I don't think it has something to do with the memory leak...

Comment: No, but you have all those listeners, potentially listening to the wrong items. And you have no control over the order in which they will be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in there: you need to make sure you remove listeners from old items when the item is updated. Remember that ListCells are reused, so updateItem(...) is called multiple times during the lifespan of your ListView.

I don't know if that's what is causing it to fail to update. This works for me:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewUpdatableProperties extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ListView<Item> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        final Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(100)));
        }
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(listView);

        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Item>, ListCell<Item>>() {

            @Override
            public ListCell<Item> call(ListView<Item> param) {
                return new ItemListCell();
            }

        });

        HBox controls = new HBox();
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Button incButton = new Button("Increment selected");
        incButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (Item item : listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
                    item.increment();
                }
            }

        });
        controls.getChildren().add(incButton);

        root.setBottom(controls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class ItemListCell extends ListCell<Item> implements InvalidationListener {

        private final HBox hbox ;
        private final Label nameLabel ;
        private final Label valueLabel ;

        public ItemListCell() {
            hbox = new HBox(5);
            nameLabel = new Label();
            valueLabel = new Label();
            hbox.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, valueLabel);
            setGraphic(hbox);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
            Item oldItem = getItem();
            if (oldItem != null) {
                oldItem.valueProperty().removeListener(this);
            }
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {
                nameLabel.setText(item.getName());
                valueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(item.getValue()));
                item.valueProperty().addListener(this);
            } else {
                nameLabel.setText("");
                valueLabel.setText("");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            final int value = getItem().getValue();
            System.out.println("Invalidated: item is "+getItem().getName() + " with value "+value);
            valueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }

    }

    public static class Item {
        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name ;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value");
        public IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return value ;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return value.get();
        }
        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value.set(value);
        }

        public void increment() {
            value.set(value.get()+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As stated in the other answer, there is no repaint() method in JavaFX. If you wire things up correctly, when the properties are invalidated, it will know to repaint.

Comment: Your example works fine. I did exactly the same as you did but in my example it still do not work. The behaviour of the listcells is absolutely strange. Sometimes the duration will be shown. But when I scroll down and up again every duration is gone and appears randomly...

I think the architecture of that javafx api part is really weird, nobody knows exactly what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Wow, now it works. My problem was that the duration value was changed by another "non-javafx thread". I'll surrounded that part with Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { ...}); Now it works. A very important point which you should know if you use JavaFX Properties.

Comment: Certainly. If changes to properties result in changes to the UI, then those changes must occur on the FX Application Thread. The behavior you describe on scrolling is exactly as expected if you omit to remove the listeners, because cells are being reused and are still "listening" to the wrong properties. The architecture is fairly well described in the [Cell API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html)

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't saw the JavaFX8 API until now. As I can see it is very well documented. Thank you James for your replies. You helped me a lot to find my bug.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX uses a "retained mode" rendering model whereas Swing uses an "immediate mode".
[See: Retained Mode Versus Immediate Mode (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So, you don't have a direct repaint() method.